# Using hostname/domain instead of IP when adding printer

Tags: windows, network-printer

**I want to install a printer that is accessible to me over the internet (from one physical location to another) without having to update the IP address each time it changes (the external IP is dynamic).**

I can install and use the printer using the IP address (ports are being forwarded through the router to the printer etc.). But if the IP changes, the connection is lost. I'm looking for a way do use a domain name (i.e. http://location.example.com) instead of an IP but I don't know how.

My router keeps the domain name updated with the current IP.

See image below:

[image: Windows 10 printer port settings dialogue]

**Update**: Is it possible to make a script in Windows that keeps the IP updated, perhaps by fetching the IP via the domain name on interval?

Comment: You will need to look into [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). For example, you could configure [DuckDNS](https://www.duckdns.org/) on a local server/PC to ensure that your DNS entry is regularly updated whenever your public IP address changes.

Comment: Please explain what exactly isn’t working how it isn’t working.

Comment: @MarkoPolo Like I said, I'm already doing that.

Comment: @DanielB I cant contact the printer via the domain name, only via the IP. What I mean is that it doesn't work as in I can't print unless I use the IP. The domain name points to the same IP.

Comment: @MarkoPolo I wrote "My router keeps the domain name updated with the current IP." Sorry If I wasn't clear enough. It's not always needed to use DuckDNS/DynDNS. My router has support for LoopiaDNS (my domain provider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That field needs to be either an IP address or a resolvable *hostname*; a FQDN won't work.

As an alternative, you could set up a VPN server on the printer's LAN, and then connect to that VPN (via your FQDN) when you want to print, at which point you should be able to just refer to the printer by it's internal (static) IP.

There are also services such as [Google Cloud Print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/).  You can [run its agent as a Windows Service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3179170) which will allow you to print to it, share it, etc. from anywhere, by using a Google account.

Comment: I've actually tried Google Cloud Print but a lot of times, the printed document has become a bit distorted resolution-wise. The concept is great though.

A VPN is also an option yes... Can a single computer use multiple VPN connections at all times? If yes, is it a good idea, or viable? I'm asking because I have three different locations that have printers. That I need available.

Comment: I'm surprised this was accepted given that we've been using FQDNs in this exact panel successfully for well over 4 years now...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i got a way around it.
 Hopefully this will be helpful too.
For me i just configured the static IP the DC as DNS.
This way the DC has to resolve computer name and actually make it possible to share through.